# Confused on direction of current through capacitors.

Tags: capacitance

I've searched and have gotten several answers. What direction does current flow when a capacitor is discharging, and which direction does current flow when it's charging?

When charging, would it be from negative to positive, and the capacitor is like a road block?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When charging, current flows into the positive side.

Comment: And when discharging current flows out of the positively charged side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to decide whether to consider the electron current model, in which current flows from the negative terminal of the voltage source in any circuit to the positive terminal, or the conventional current model which is the opposite.

Taking electron current, and putting a capacitor in the circuit, the charging current flows from the negative terminal of the voltages source to the negative terminal of the capacitor, and from the positive terminal of the capacitor to the positive terminal of the voltage source.  It effectively flows from negative to positive across the capacitor.   Discharging is the opposite.

For conventional current, all of the above is reversed.

Comment: Based on your electron charging direction. How could it flow to negative? Like charges repel don't they? Is it acting as a roadblock with no where else to go then?

Comment: The electron flow into one side of the capacitor _makes_ it negative.  The  electrons are forced to do this because the voltage source has even stronger repulsion between electrons than the ones that are being packed into the capacitor.  The electrons can't flow across the dielectric material in the capacitor so they accumulate on the negative side.  Meanwhile, electrons are drawn out of the other side to the positive terminal of the voltage source.  This constitutes an "effective" flow through the capacitor.

Comment: If you measure with a voltmeter on the two terminals of the capacitor, the negative terminal is the one receiving electrons from the source.  BUT a second voltmeter measuring from the negative terminal of the voltage source to the negative terminal of the capacitor would show that it is more positive than the source terminal until the capacitor is fully charged, at which time that voltage would be zero.

Comment: @D.Ennis Your comments are very helpful in developing a "working model" of circuits. Thank you!